# Validating absolute path using Uri - Uri.IsWellFormedUriString and Uri.TryCreate behaves different

Tags: c#, uri, .net-4.5

I am checking whether an absolute path is correct from a C# app.
In order to do this I use Uri.IsWellFormedUriString and also Uri.TryCreate as below:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myPath = "\\\\myMac\\Home\\Desktop\\Testing\\TestFiles";                               
        
        Uri outUri;
        bool isWellFormed= Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(myPath, UriKind.Absolute);
        bool isUriCreated = Uri.TryCreate(myPath, UriKind.Absolute, out outUri);
            
        Console.WriteLine("UriWellFormed: "+ isWellFormed);
        Console.WriteLine("IsUriCreated: " + isUriCreated);
        
        if (isWellFormed &&
            isUriCreated &&
            outUri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes, this is a valid Uri string");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid Uri string");
        }       
    }
}
```

You can see a demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K3rKIg):

Uri.IsWellFormedUriString is returning false. However Uri.TryCreate is returning true.

Above code returns below results:

```
UriWellFormed: False
IsUriCreated: True
Not a valid Uri string
```

So why Uri.IsWellFromedUriSring is returning false and then the Uri is successfully created using Uri.TryCreate?

Comment: If you look at the output of `Uri.TryCreate` - `file://mymac/Home/Desktop/Testing/TestFiles` then *that’s* a well formed URI

Comment: @stuartd Yes, but it is supposed that Uri.IsWellFormedUriString checks whether myPath is well-formed by attempting to construct a URI with it as said here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-6.0

so in fact it should be the same as Uri.TryCreate does which tries/attempts to create/construct an Uri with myPath. Is not the same? or maybe I am not understanding the meaning of these methods? Both should return true I think.

Comment: A `\\\` path is **not a URI**. It’s a filepath.

Comment: From the docs you linked to - _” The string is considered poorly formed, causing the method to return false, if any of the following conditions occur”_ - and then -  _”The string is an absolute Uri that represents an implicit file Uri.”_ - to be honest here though I don’t understand your question. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @stuartd Well, i am trying to check if a path is correct. I do not understand why IsWellFormedUriString behaves different than TryCreate. In fact both check if the string is correct for construct an URI so I am wondering why they do not behave the same.